# using a local version of vim instead of system on CentOS

Tags: ssh, vim, centos

My school runs centos and a dated version of vim. i want to use a new version of vim so I can have access to stuff I otherwise wouldnt. I built and configured a 7.4.300 version of vim with python, lua etc and maked it with success. since the build doesn't have colors/syntaxes though it looks dumb and gives errors when it loads my vimrc. Is there a configure option to include these builtin colors/syntaxes or a way to change the lookup to look for the system vim's settings?

Answer (score 1):

For installing color schemes create two folders in your home directories!

[user@vembuserver]mkdir ~/.vim

[user@vembuserver]mkdir ~/.vim/colors

Now you will need the theme configuration files. You can download the latest color schemes and many old ones from [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) (official website of vim editor).

Now for each theme, you will get a .vim file or an zipped archive which after extracting will produce lots of .vim files

Now you have to copy all the files to the directory .vim/colors/ in your home directory.

For example, if you have downloaded a theme called matrix.vim, then -

[user@vembuserver]mv matrix.vim ~/.vim/colors

Voila, the colorscheme is installed, now whenever you are editing a file, you can change the colorscheme using

:colorscheme matrix.vim
You can install as many themes as you like by copying files into that directory.

Now if you want to make a theme your default theme, then you should add this command to your .vimrc -

colorscheme matrix

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

If you configured, built and installed your 7.4.300 Vim properly, you should have the standard syntax and color scheme files already. Start `vim` and execute

```
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
```

That will tell you where your `vim` thinks your runtime files are installed. To see if anything is there, execute

```
:!ls $VIMRUNTIME
```

That should give you a list of files and directories including the `colors` and `syntax` directories.

If either of those commands isnot working as described, then your configuration needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fully configured self-built Vim, you need to *install* it. But you don't need to install it to the system directory, don't worry! When you build, specify a build prefix by using the `--prefix` option when you run the `./configure` command. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9801429/1390430 shows how to configure a build that will install to a particular directory. A web search will turn up several more. Just use a directory you can write to for the build prefix, build Vim, do a `make install`, make sure that directory lies on your PATH variable, and you're set to go!